# Cannot set checkbox to checked using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onclick

I have the following javascript function. A the top of the function, I am able to detect if a checkbox is checked using $(elem).is(':checked'). Later in the function I want to wire up an onclick event in a modal window such that it will checkmark the elem's checkbox, but this does not seem to work.

Here is the function:

```
function toggleProductChkBx(elem,id)
    {
        if ($(elem).is(':checked')) {

        } else {

            $('#clearProductModal').on('show', function () {
                removeBtn = $(this).find('.danger');
                removeBtn.click(function () { clearProduct(id) });

                cancelBtn = $(this).find('.secondary');

                //THIS IS THE LINE THAT IS NOT WORKING
                cancelBtn.click(function () { $(elem).attr("checked", "true"); });

            })
            .modal({ backdrop: true });
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check a checkbox with jQuery or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using 1.9.1

Comment: Also tried $(elem).checked(true); - no love.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

`cancelBtn.click(function () { $(elem).attr("checked", "true"); });`

To

`cancelBtn.click(function () { $(elem).prop("checked", true); });`

Comment: `.prop('checked', true)` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(elem).attr("checked", true);
```